# Можно ли подключить шрифт при переводе страницы

Tags: html, css

Ситуация такая: имеется сайт использующий шрифт определенной языковой группы, понятное дело, при переводе страницы средствами хром, мозилла и т.д. едет верстка, поскольку используемый шрифт имеет межбуквенное расстояние гораздо больше, чем кириллица и латиница. 
Заказчик требует устранить "баг верстки", но сколько бы я ни искал инфы по этому вопросу, прихожу ко мнению, что это не исправить никак, кроме верстки отдельного сайта на кириллице/латинице, использующего корректный шрифт.
Или я не прав?
Как вариант, заказчик, предложил установить запрет на перевод блока/блоков. Но, опять же, на мой взгляд, это невозможно.

Comment: Попробуйте на JavaScript'e отслеживать происходит ли перевод и применять соответственные font-size или font-family к элементам

Comment: Вы хоть картинку или пример дайте чтоб хоть потестить проблему. В вики китайскую страницу перевожу верстка норм https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%8D%8E%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%91%E5%85%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%9B%BD%E8%A2%AB%E5%B0%81%E9%94%81%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8 что же у вас за шрифт?

Comment: шрифт KozGoPro (японский), вторым указан Tahoma, но в случае перевода не работает. Если нужна картинка: https://prnt.sc/iks8mt

Comment: stckvrw, а как можно отследить? "Великий оракул" ответа не даёт(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему получается так что нужно использовать шрифт с поддержкой кирилицы. Остальное костыли той или иной степени.

Ну как вариант можно следить за изменением содержимого и проверять из какого алфавита символы. И менять шрифты. В примере я использовал SimSun шрифт, так как он тоже плохо переносит кириллицу.

К сожалению тут код не работает, тк большая часть сайта на русском и онлайн переводчик не срабатывает.

```js
function fixedCharCodeAt (str, idx) {
    var code = str.charCodeAt(idx);
    if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) { 
        // Верхний вспомогательный символ
        var hi = code;
        var low = str.charCodeAt(idx+1);
        return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
    }
    if (0xDC00 <= code && code <= 0xDFFF) { 
       // Нижний вспомогательный символ
        var hi = str.charCodeAt(idx-1);
        var low = code;
        return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
    }
    return code;
}
document.getElementById("testdiv").addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  mydiv=document.getElementById("testdiv");
  //самая простая проверка - читаем код первого символа в юникоде
  //лучше проверять большее число символов так как перевод текста может быть частичным
  //если <1280 то кирилица или латиница
  c=fixedCharCodeAt(mydiv.textContent,0);
  if (c<1280) {
    //обнаружили кирилицу
    document.body.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma";
  } else {
    document.body.style.fontFamily = "SimSun";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
body {
font-family: 'SimSun';
}
```

```html
<div id="testdiv">サイト翻訳サ</div>

<div style="font-family: 'SimSun';">サイト翻訳サ</div>
```

Вот код целиком чтобы проверить локально

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
font-family: 'SimSun';
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="testdiv">サイト翻訳サ</div>

<div style="font-family: 'SimSun';">サイト翻訳サ</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//функция чтобы узнать код символа в юникоде
function fixedCharCodeAt (str, idx) {
    var code = str.charCodeAt(idx);
    if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) { 
        // Верхний вспомогательный символ
        var hi = code;
        var low = str.charCodeAt(idx+1);
        return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
    }
    if (0xDC00 <= code && code <= 0xDFFF) { 
       // Нижний вспомогательный символ
        var hi = str.charCodeAt(idx-1);
        var low = code;
        return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
    }
    return code;
}
document.getElementById("testdiv").addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  mydiv=document.getElementById("testdiv");
  //самая простая проверка - читаем код первого символа в юникоде
  //лучше проверять большее число символов так как перевод текста может быть частичным
  //если <1280 то кирилица или латиница
  c=fixedCharCodeAt(mydiv.textContent,0);
  if (c<1280) {
    //обнаружили кирилицу
    document.body.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma";
  } else {
    document.body.style.fontFamily = "SimSun";
  }
}, false);        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Нет слов. Спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Можно к примеру, когда отрабатывает скрипт перевода, доставлять класс верстки. В котором поменять размеры шрифтов и межстрочные интервалы. Самый простой способ реализации.

Comment: Лучше шрифт менять. Так как шрифт не поддерживающий кирилицу выглядит все равно не очень даже если интервал между буквами уменьшить.

Answer (score 0):

В Chrome при переводе страницы добавляется класс `translated-ltr` или `translated-rtl`, а при показе оригинального текста - удаляется.
Собственно осталось отследить изменение атрибута.

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
    callback = function(mutationsList) {
        if(html.className.match('translated')){
            console.log('Страница переведена');
        }else{
            console.log('Оригинальная страница');
        }
    };
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(html, {attributes: true});
```

JavaScript, как таковой, не обязателен. Ибо можно манипулировать через CSS

```
body {
    font-family: 'KozGoPro';
}
html.translated-ltr body {
    font-family: 'Tahoma';
}
```

PS:
Для мозилы и т. д.
Например добавляем div со словом "Computer" и id="langchange". При событии проверяем регуляркой на кириллицу. Оригинальная страница на английском.

```
if(typeof MutationObserver == 'function'){
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
        div = document.getElementById('langchange'),
        config = {
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            subtree: true,
            characterDataOldValue: true
        },
        callback = function(mutationsList) {
            var text = mutationsList[0].target.textContent;
            if(/^[А-Яа-я]+/.test(text)){
                console.log('Страница Переведена');
                html.classList.add('translate');
            }else{
                console.log('Оригинальная страница');
                html.classList.remove('translate');
            }
        };
    var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer.observe(div, config);
}
```

Comment: Проблема не столько в хроме. Необходима поддержка всех браузеров.

Comment: Ну так использовать MutationObserver можно по разному.
Отредактирую свой комментарий